# Adding Firebase dependencies to Android Project with settings.gradle file

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have big struggles with the configuration of my Android Gradle Project. I tried a large number of solutions found on the internet, but still can't build and run my project successfully. I try to add Firebase libraries to my app.

The app was generated via the latest Android Studio Navigation Template.

Here are my gradle files:

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        gradlePluginPortal()
//        jcenter()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "RowingBG Achievements"
include ':app'
```

build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        gradle_version = "8.0.2"
        kotlin_version = '1.8.20'
        gms_version = '4.3.15'
    }
 //    repositories {
 //        google()
 //        mavenCentral()
 //        gradlePluginPortal()
 //        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
 //        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 //    }

 //    dependencies {
 //        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
 //        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
 //        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.41'
 //        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:$gms_version"
 //    }
 }
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version "$gradle_version" apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version "$gradle_version" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "$kotlin_version" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "$gms_version" apply false
 }

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
```

build.gradle (Module:App)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    namespace 'com.bzahov.rowingbg'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bzahov.rowingbg"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
dependencies { 
     // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-ktx"


...}
```

I got so strange errors:

> No variants found for ':app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists. at:
> com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidModule.prepare(GradleModules.kt:266)

After I resolved this one I got folowing one:

> **Could not find** com.google.firebase:firebase-core:.
> Required by:
> project :app
> Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-ktx
> Add Google Maven repository and sync project
> Affected Modules: app

and

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

[image]

when I sync project I get these warnings like my project don't access **Google Maven repository**[image]

I tried a lot of different approaches but I don't have enough knowledge on new Settings. Gradle Approach. Can you help me resolve the issues or give me some advice and guidance?

**I will be very grateful if you could help me to solve it because I already tried to do it alone, without success, for so much time**

Thank you for your help in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in build.gradle (Module:App) you should remove `-ktx` from `"com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-ktx"`:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth"
```

Comment: I removed firebase-core and do as you suggested, removed -ktx, and that fixed my problems . Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The line of code that is causing you problems is:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
```

Which is also currently [deprecated](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#core_v21-1-1). Besides that, you have removed the `kotlin-android` and `kotlin-kapt` plugins. To solve this, please add the following dependencies in your configuration files:

settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "RowingBG Achievements"
include ':app'
```

build.gradle (Project):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        gradle_version = '7.4.0'
        kotlin_version = '1.8.20'
        google_services_version = '4.3.15'
        firebase_bom_version = '32.0.0'
        play_services_auth_version = '20.5.0'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:$google_services_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version "${gradle_version}" apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version "${gradle_version}" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "${kotlin_version}" apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (Module:App):

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "kotlin-kapt"
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
}

android {
    namespace "com.bzahov.rowingbg"
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bzahov.rowingbg"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    //Firebase
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:$firebase_bom_version")
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx"
    //Play Services Auth
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$play_services_auth_version"
}
```

Please note that these dependencies will work for implementing Firebase products. However, you also need to add the corresponding dependencies for Android.

Comment: **Thank you very much!!** Yesterday I removed firebase-core and then find out as @Silviya suggested I should remove **-ktx**  from **gms:play-services-auth**. Both answers solve the problem